# How to hang floats in outer margins with floatrow in twoside documents

Tags: floatrow

In this document I tried to have wide figures hang in the outside margins.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[widefigure]{margins=hangoutside}

\begin{document}
~\newpage % just to get a spread
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure*}[htbp]
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure*}[htbp]
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

the spread on pp. 2–3 looks like this:

[image]

So only on p. 2 is the outer margin used. With margins=hanginside I'll get the opposite. In my original document I assumed I got a problem because of interfering packages, but there is not much else in this file. Is this a problem with floatrow, or something I've misunderstood?

Comment: The `margins=hanginside` only works on one page because its a two side document. So on each page the inner and outer margins are opposed to each other. Do you want the figure to hand always to the left? Or always to the outside?

Comment: I use hangoutside exactly because it *is* a twoside document. There are hangleft and hangright to always hang to left/right, and then there are these options that according to the documentation does different things for oneside and twoside layouts.

Comment: For me this seems to be a bug in that package, you should report the maintainer a bug report ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had assumed that `margins=hangoutside` would be enough to do what I wanted, but there is another option `facing` that also needs to be set:

> This key defines whether facing layout is used for floats, if it is
>   switched on, key options, which create different layout for even
>   and odd pages are switched on.

So the solution is to just change the floatsetup line to

```
\floatsetup[widefigure]{margins=hangoutside,facing=yes}
```

and that spread will look as I wanted:
[image]